# What's the best way to switch between scenes in JavaFX?

Tags: javafx

I'm developing a menu using plain `JavaFX` (no CSS or FXML) but I can't figure out a good way to switch between scenes.

I want to have a fixed `primaryStage` whose content I can change.

I have a class for everything in the menu (New Game, Options, Info and Exit). If I create a `start()` method for every class my program it doesn't work, but i also wouldn't like to create a new stage for everything.

How can I fix this?

Comment: "If I create a `start()` method for every class". Why would you want to do that? The `start()` method starts the application: you only need to do that once.

Answer (score 0):

in your main class (the one that extends Application) have a variable

```
private static Stage primaryStage;
```

and set that in your `start(Stage primaryStage)` method

then create a getter in your main class

```
public static Stage getPrimaryStage() {
    return this.primaryStage;
}
```

now you can access the primaryStage from anywhere using `MyClass.getPrimaryStage()` and set the scene of that stage from anywhere. :)

Comment: Doesn't that produce the error: `non-static variable this cannot be referenced from a static context
        return this.primaryStage;`

Comment: If you access it with `MyClass.getPrimaryStage()` instead of `classObject.getPrimaryStage()` it shouldn't be a problem.